# Asymptotic behaviour for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems

Imagine I have an ordinary linear homogeneous second-order differential equation of the form:
$$
y''=f(x)y'+g(x)y,
$$
where the functions $f$ and $g$ have the regularity you wish, are bounded, and satisfy
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=a, \qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=b,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real constants.

Heuristically, this tells that the asymptotics of a solution of our ODE will behave as the solution of the autonomous ODE:
$$
v''=av'+bv.
$$

For example, if we have a solution for the first equation, $y$, converging to zero, and $v$ is a solution for the second equation converging to zero (i.e., exponential decay), do we have
$$
y(x)=O(v(x)),\qquad v(x)=O(y(x))
$$
as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

**EDIT:**
To clarify my question, I will point out here an example suggested in one of the answers. Let $f(x)=e^{-x}+1$ ang $g(x)=0$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
y''(x)+(e^{-x}+1)y'(x)=0 \implies y(x) = c_1e^{e^{-x}}+c_2.
\end{equation}
And between all these solutions, take for example the ones converging to zero, so take $c_1=-c_2$.

I claim that asymptotically this solution and the solutions converging to zero of the approximation
\begin{equation}
y''(x)+y'(x)=0 \implies y(x) = \tilde{c}e^{-x}
\end{equation}
are the same. In this case, this is true, since
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{c_1e^{e^{-x}}-c_1}{\tilde{c}e^{-x}}=c_1/\tilde{c}.
$$

**Question:**
Is this true in general? If so, is there any kind of result I can use to formalize this? Note that I assumed the solutions to converge to zero for simplicity, but I think the asymptotics would be the same between any two reasonable solutions (as far as we do not compare solutions with a finite limit and solutions going to infinity, for example).

I have tried to compute the error between the approximation and the first solution, and prove that this error has a faster decay than the solution itself, but it didn't work.

Comment: A trivial solution to the ODE $y'' = y' + y$ is $y = e^{x}$, which would suggest $a + b = 1$. More generally, the ODE can be a foundation to the family of curves $me^{nx}, m, n \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $y' = mne^{nx} \text{ and } y'' = mn^2 e^{nx} \implies mn^2 = amn + bm$, which should make $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ (since, $m, n, mn^2 \in \mathbb{R}$). However, this is not a strong proof and I still feel like there are some loopholes I missed. Nonetheless, you can use this as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see the relation of this with my question

Comment: Well, is your question to prove $a$ and $b$ are real constants?

Comment: The "verify" should be "satisfy", it is the assumption that these limits exist, not the task to prove it. The question proper is in the last sentence, in what way can the solutions of the constant-coefficient equation serve as asymptotes in the original equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ahh, I see.

Comment: What if we define a new variable as the difference between the solutions? When does it converge to zero?

Comment: @Arastas Mm I do not see what you mean, since the difference between the two solutions is not a solution of any of the equations. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I think it's likely to be false, if you pick a function that approaches the limit slowly enough -- eg I would look at $f(x)=a+x^{-\epsilon}$ closely

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have that much accuracy with that weak assumptions. Take $y(x)=e^{-x}$ solving $y''=y$, say. Now take $Y(x)=xe^{-x}$. Then $Y''=(x-2)e^{-x}=\frac{x-2}xY$ (assuming the domain $x\ge 1$, say), so they satisfy asymptotically the same equation but $Y$ is much larger near $\infty$. In general, just take any exponentially decaying solution of any equation with constant coefficients, multiply it by any function whose derivatives are o-small of its value as $x\to\infty$ and you will construct a similar example with pretty much any sub-exponential deviation. The life gets better if you impose some particular speed of convergence of $f$ and $g$ to their limiting values, but it is a separate story.

Comment: Mm interesting. And what would happen if I impose that the speed of convergence of $f$ and $g$ is, let's say, exponential decay with decay rate $1$?

Answer (score 2):

Counter example (I think):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}+1$ and $g(x)=0$ so that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 1.
\end{equation}
We have that
\begin{equation}
y''(x)+(e^{-x}+1)y'(x)=0 \implies y(x) = c_1e^{e^{-x}}+c_2.
\end{equation}
From your heuristic proposition we have:
\begin{equation}
y''(x)+y'(x)=0 \implies y(x) = c_1e^{-x}+c_2.
\end{equation}
Lastly, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} c_1e^{e^{-x}}+c_2 = c_1+c_2 \neq c_2 = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}  c_1e^{-x}+c_2.
\end{equation}
which completes the counter example.

Comment: The example is nice, the conclusion is not so clear. The constant in solution and asymptote can be different, so noting is preventing $c_2=\bar c_1+\bar c_2$ so that both converge to the same constant. The question is does the speed of convergence justify calling it "asymptote". But even that is not so much in question if you write the solution as $c_1(e^{e^{-x}}-1)+c_2$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! But I think this does not apply as a counterexample: you are taking the same constants for the solution of both equations, which in general is not true. In this case, if you take solutions converging to zero for both equations (like $Ce^{e^{-x}}-1$ and $\tilde{C}e^{-x}$), they have the same asymptotics (note that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{Ce^{e^{-x}}-1}{\tilde{C}e^{-x}}=C/\tilde{C}$). Sorry if the explanation of my question was not clear enough.

Comment: Okay, no free lunch! However, if you added the initial conditions, $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ for example, then you get (for my examples of f and g): Actual answer $y(x) = 1 - \exp(e^{-x}- 1)$; and the heuristic answer $y(x) = 1-e^{-x}$. Both of these have different limits as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, it can be addressed as follows.

Define $\tilde f(x) := f(x) - a$ and $\tilde g(x) := g(x) - b$. Let $y(x)$ be the solution of $y'' = f(x)y'+g(x)y$ and $z$ be the solution of $z'' = az'+bz$. Define $e(x) = y(x)-z(x)$. Then $e' = y'-z'$ and $$e'' = \tilde f(x)y' + ay' + \tilde g(x) y + b y - az' - bz$$ that is $$e'' = ae' + b e + \tilde f(x)y' + \tilde g(x) y.$$
The solution $y$ converges to $z$ iff $e$ goes to zero. For that one, we need that

- the solution $z$ of $z'' = az'+bz$ is (exponentially) converging to zero (**upd:** $a$ and $b$ both negative)
- the extra term $\tilde f(x)y' + \tilde g(x) y$ converges to zero, e.g., $y$ and $y'$ are bounded.

I would say that the second item follows from the first under some assumptions on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: But in this way you cannot deduce the decay of the error for long time, right?

Comment: @Jotabeta Sorry, I am not sure if I follow. As I wrote, $e$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity under the two assumptions. Moreover, I would say that all you need is only $a<0$, $b<0$, and $f$ and $g$ such that $y$ exists for all $x$ and is unique. Then at some $x$, the dynamics of $y$ will become stable, converging to $0$. As $z$ does.

Comment: @Jotabeta Just to be sure that we are talking about the same. What do you mean by "long time"? Do you consider $x$ as the time variable?

Comment: So what I mean is the following: I choose in both equations a solution converging to zero, and the question is do they converge with the "same" speed? I.e., the decay rate of a solution converging to zero for the first equation and the decay rate of a solution converging to zero for the second equation (the approximation) are the same?

Comment: @Jotabeta Ok, I see the updated question. As for me, the big O notation is as follows: $y(x) = \mathcal{O}(v(x))$ means $\exists$ $x_0$, $K$ such that $|y| \le K |v|$ $\forall x \ge x_0$. Both $y$ and $v$ converge to zero exponentially, and $|y|\le C_y e^{-\lambda x}$, $|v|\le C_v e^{-\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda<0$.

Comment: @Jotabeta However, I am unsure if the exponential convergence implies what you ask.

Comment: Exactly, my problem is to check if the $\lambda$ is the same for $v$ and for $y$.

Comment: @Jotabeta It is a conservative upper bound. Even if $\lambda$ was not the same, you could take the slowest. However, in your case, it is the same value.

Comment: Sorry for being repetitive, but how do you know it is the same in my case?

Comment: @Jotabeta Hmm... Probably not the same. Let $\lambda_v>0$ be the one for $v$ : $|v|\le C_v e^{-\lambda_v x}$ for some $C_v$. Then I clam that for any $0<\lambda_y<\lambda_v$ there exists $C_y$ such that $|y| \le C_y e^{-\lambda_y x}$. Not exactly the same, but arbitrary close.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I gave the bounty to the answer of @fedja, due to his clarifying counterexample, I think it would be useful to also write here what I have discovered about this topic.

As the counterexample shows, the statement is not true in general. But we can still say something if we have more information about the functions $f$ and $g$.

Assume $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1(x), \lambda_2(x)\}$ is a complete set of roots for the characteristic equation
$$
r^2-f(x)r-g(x)=0.
$$
Then if $\Lambda$ posses certain technical properties which I am not going to develop here (roughly speaking, we are asking for the asymptotics of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ to be different enough), then the differential equation
$$
y''-f(x)y'-g(x)y=0
$$
has a fundamental system of solutions of the form
$$
y_1(x)=\exp \left[\int\gamma_1(x)\, dx \right], \qquad y_2(x)=\exp \left[\int\gamma_2(x)\, dx \right]
$$
where $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are functions satisfying
$$
\gamma_1(x)\sim \lambda_1(x), \qquad \gamma_2(x)\sim \lambda_2(x)
$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty$. The details of this statement and a proof can be found in the book "Asymptotics of Linear Differential Equations" by Lanstman, Theorem 10.29.

**Example:**

In the comments, the following example was given as a proof that my original statement was not correct, but we can see that it is easy to find the asymptotics of such an equation with the theorem just mentioned. Consider the ODE:
$$
y''=\frac{x-2}{x}y,
$$
and we look for the asymptotics of any solution approaching zero. In this case, the function $g(x)=\frac{x-2}{x}$ satisfies all the conditions of the theorem (if you do not believe me, check the book I cited). And the set
$$
\left\{\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x}}, -\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x}}\right\}
$$
is a complete set of roots for the corresponding characteristic equation. Since
$$
\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x}}=1-\frac{1}{x}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})
$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty$, then we have that every solution approaching zero will behave as
$$
\exp \left[\int - \sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x}}\right]=\exp \left[\int -x+\frac{1}{x}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})\right]\sim  Cxe^{-x}.
$$
We can double-check this with the general explicit solutions of our equation that approach zero: $y(x)=Cxe^{-x}$. (The fact that we obtained exactly the solution of the equation is a coincidence, the theorem only gives the asymptotic behavior of the solutions, not their explicit form).

Comment: F. W. J. Olver's book, *Asymptotics and Special Functions* is also a good source. Especially Chapter 6.